# How to integrate diagrams.net/draw.io with self-hosted GitLab

Tags: app.diagrams.net, gitlab

`diagrams.net` (formerly known as `draw.io`) integrates with GitLab. However, when I try to authenticate, it redirects me to `gitlab.com` when I'd like to connect to a self-hosted GitLab instance at `company.gitlab.com`. How do I tell `diagrams.net` to authenticate to my self-hosted GitLab instance instead?

Comment: A year has passed. Have you found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can only do that with a self-hosted draw.io instance. You also need to have your gitlab admin configure an application first.

In short:

1. Add application to gitlab.company.com. The REDIRECT_URI would be something like https://drawio.company.com/gitlab.html (the gitlab.html is important)
2. The Application ID needs to go to draw.io conf file as window.DRAWIO_GITLAB_ID
3. In the same config set window.DRAWIO_GITLAB_URL to your gitlab instance, like https://gitlab.company.com
4. The secret token from gitlab is not required.

If you run your self-hosted draw.io in docker, you can pass the configuration as env vars. In this case omit the window. part

Comment: Hi @Mike Hofmann, I followed your instructions but it's not working, it redirects to gitlab instead of .html and if I add .html after it redirects, it doesn't do anything